# Sinon and mocking default properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, sinon

Let's say I have the following files/code:

#### Person.ts

```js
export class Person {
    id: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    isEmployed: boolean = true;
    isManager: boolean = false;

    public static Name = ():string => this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
}
```

#### WorkHistory.ts

```js
import { Person } from './person';

export class WorkHistory {
   public propA: string;
   public propB: string;

   public getHistory = (p: Person): any => { 
      // do something
      // return history
   }; 
}
```

#### Formatter.ts

```js
import { Person } from './person';
import { WorkHistory } from './workHistory';

export class Formatter {
   public formatWork(p: Person) {
       let wh: WorkHistory = new WorkHistory();
       let whData = wh.getHistory(p);

       // do formatting
       // return formatting
   }
}
```

I'm trying to write a unit test for the `formatWork` method.  However, I can't figure out how to stub out `WorkHistory` and its properties.

Here's what I've got so far:

#### Formatter.spec.ts

```js
describe('formatWork', () => {
   let mockWorkHistory = {
      propA: '',
      propB: ''
   };
   let sandbox;
   let formatter;

   beforeEach(() => {
      sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
      sandbox.stub(WorkHistory, "prototype").value(mockWorkHistory);
   });

   afterEach(() => {
      sandbox.restore();
   });

   it('should do something', () => {
       // create person object
       formatter = new Formatter();
       var result = formatter.formatWork(person);

       console.log(result);
   });
});
```

I've tried stubs and `sandbox.replace`, however, I can't seem to overwrite `WorkHistory` default properties or methods.

As it stands, the above throws an exception in Phantom 2.1.1:
`TypeError: Attempting to change enumerable attribute of unconfigurable property.`

Additionally, the `console.log` in my fixture shows all of the default properties for `WorkHistory` instead of the overwritten values.

What am I missing?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having to use `ts-mock-imports` since I was using webpack.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Sinon only can't cover all your requirements. You need some tools to mock your import, like `genMockFromModule` in Jest or [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire)

Sinon is a pretty convenient way to generate stub, but the tool knows nothing about your module structure. And you should find a way how to pass your Sinon-mocked class to the module that you are testing.